# Why does a fluid flows?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, flow, continuum-mechanics

I was reading about viscosity and momentum diffusion in Physical Chemistry and I came up with the title. Suppose we have some amount of liquid inside a container with a piston (initially fixed) in the horizontial direcion. If we let the piston free why does the liquid move in the horizontal direction? Is it because it exerts pressure in the piston? The liquid initially wasn't moving so some kind of energy should be converted into kinetic energy. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The fluid exerts pressure on the walls of the container. The pressure arises from the fact that due to gravity the upper layers of the fluid push on the lower ones.

The pressure pushes the piston which starts moving. 
As the height of the fluid lowers, the gravitational potential energy of the fluid is converted into kinetic energy of the piston.

Answer (score 0):

> The liquid initially wasn't moving so some kind of energy should be
>   converted into kinetic energy

That is the point. The liquid is always moving at the molecular level. If molecules were static as very small grains of sand, the property called pressure didn't exist, and some effects like communicating vessels won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question can be rephrased as why a fluid “falls horizontally”, displacing the lateral piston, and that the reasons are two: it “falls” because of gravity and it falls “horizontally” because you are talking about a fluid and more so if it is a liquid.

Remember the differences between a fluid and a solid and between a gas and a liquid. It is a question of degrees of cohesion among particles and the thresholds are:  so much cohesion that the particles cooperate to maintain volume and shape (a solid); they cooperate less and only keep volume, not shape (a liquid); the cooperate so little that they keep neither volume nor shape (a gas).

This affects the way of falling. A solid, like a concrete cube, falls purely vertically, since all its particles jointly collaborate in trying to penetrate the ground, not caring about the lateral piston. At the other end, in a gas, there is minimum cooperation: particles collide against each other and bounce around, so they do press on the lateral piston, but are less effective since their efforts are scattered, as they also have an "upper job", i.e. knocking on the top lid.  In the intermediate case, the liquid, the particles are still free to move, unlike in the solid; but unlike in a gas they don’t bounce against each other: they have enough cohesion so that -if they find an impenetrable ground- they slide over one another attempting to keep falling; hence when they encounter the lateral piston, they are more effective in displacing it, because they are more focused, having no "upper job".